# Add/Edit data in a SQL database using HTML Forms Text Input boxes

Tags: java, sql, jsp, netbeans

I am working on a Java Web Application in NetBeans. I have made a JSP page that can add a row to a SQL database, but I want to allow for user input. To this end, I have made some Text Input boxes. I want the user to be able to enter in a string and then have those strings saved as varchar data to the SQL database. Is there a way to make this happen?

Here is the code for making one of the text input:

```
<p>Name</p>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="100"/>
```

Here is the code for adding a row to the database:

```
    <sql:update var="attempt1" dataSource="jdbc/testaddressbook">
        INSERT INTO people (fullName, address, telephone, email)
        VALUES ("testerName3", "testerAddress", "testerPhone", "testerEmail")
    </sql:update>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some basic understanding of [JDBC (Java Data Base Connectivity)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) and [Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html). There are tons of way to achieve what you want, but below is a minimal example to give you some idea:

**1. Create a servlet to handle the user input and insert the data into SQL**

```
package mycoolapp;

public RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Obtain submitted form data
    String name = req.getParameterName("Name");
    String address = req.getParameterName("Address");
    String phone = req.getParameterName("Phone");
    String email = req.getParameterName("Email");

    // Setup your database datasource, this is different for each db vendor. On production environment most likely you need a connection pooled datasource
    DataSource ds = // setup ds here..
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    // Prepare the SQL statement to insert, plug in the values
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO people (fullName, address, telephone, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    stmt.setString(1, name);
    stmt.setString(2, address);
    stmt.setString(3, phone);
    stmt.setString(4, email);

    // Execute the insert
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    conn.close();

    // Dispatch into success page
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/registerSuccess.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(req, res);
  }
}
```

**2. Declare and map the servlet on your WEB-INF/web.xml deployment descriptor**

Below setting will map the servlet into `http://myhost/mywarname/register`

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-class>mycoolapp.RegistrationServlet</servlet-class>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationServlet</servlet-name>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**3. Configure your form to post into the servlet**

```
<form method="post" action="register">
  ....
</form>
```

**Few words of warning:**

- Servlet code above does not come with appropriate exception and error handling
- JDBC code above does not come with appropriate transaction management
- The above example is by no mean the industry standard best practice, it is in fact an old & obsolete approach. It shows the fundamental how java servlets and database interaction works. When you're building a proper application, consider using web framework such as [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework), [JSF](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html) or others.